# Need help converting from prototype to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, prototype

I need help converting the below code. I have a software that uses prototype but it really really conflicts with jquery. I have used online auto scripts to translate code, did nothing, i tried to manually do it but i don't have enough knowledge, and i tried using $.noconflict but it had no effect, and no help. - Please if anyone can help with the code below:

```
var menuList = new Array();
var buttonList = new Array();
var scriptList = new Array();

/* Ajax post request */
function scriptDoLoadPost(scriptUrl, scriptForm, scriptPos, scriptArgs, noLoading) {
    if(!scriptArgs){ var scriptArgs = ''; }
    scriptArgs = $(scriptForm).serialize() + scriptArgs;
    myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(scriptPos, scriptUrl, {
        method : 'post',
        parameters : scriptArgs,
        evalScripts : true,
        onLoading: function(request){ showLoadingIcon(scriptPos, noLoading); },
        insertion : Insertion.Append
    });
}

/* Ajax get request */
function scriptDoLoad(scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs, noLoading) {
    myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(scriptPos, scriptUrl, {
        method : 'get',
        parameters : scriptArgs,
        evalScripts : true,
        onLoading : function(request){ showLoadingIcon(scriptPos, noLoading); },
        insertion : Insertion.Append
    });
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

/* site map request */
function sitemapDoLoadPost(scriptUrl, scriptForm, scriptPos, scriptArgs, noLoading) {

    hideDiv('proceed');
    showDiv('message');
    if(!scriptArgs){ var scriptArgs = ''; }
    scriptArgs = $(scriptForm).serialize() + scriptArgs;
    myAjax = new Ajax.Updater(scriptPos, scriptUrl, {
        method : 'post',
        parameters : scriptArgs,
        evalScripts : true,
        onLoading: function(request){ showLoadingIcon(scriptPos, noLoading); }
    }); 
}

/* Onloading image icon function */
function showLoadingIcon(scriptPos,noLoading){
    loading = 0;
    contentDiv = "";
    switch (scriptPos){     

        case "content":
            contentDiv = '<div id="loading_content"></div>';
            loading = 1;
            break;

        case "subcontent":
            contentDiv = '<div id="loading_subcontent"></div>';
            loading = 1;
            break;

        case "ContentFrame":
            contentDiv = '<div id="loading_content_frame"></div>';
            loading = 1;
            break;

        case "subcontmed":
            contentDiv = '<div id="loading_subcontmed"></div>';
            loading = 1;
            break;

        case "newsalert":
            contentDiv = '<div id="loading_longthin"></div>';
            loading = 1;
            break;

        default :
            contentDiv = '<div id="loading_rankarea"></div>';
            loading = 1;
            break;
    }

    if((loading == 1) && (noLoading != 1)){
        document.getElementById(scriptPos).innerHTML = contentDiv;
    }
}

function confirmLoad(scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs) {

    if (chkObject('wantproceed')) {
        wantproceed = "Do you really want to proceed?";
    }

    var agree = confirm(wantproceed);
    if (agree)
        return scriptDoLoad(scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs);
    else
        return false;
}

function confirmSubmit(scriptUrl, scriptForm, scriptPos, scriptArgs) {

    if(!scriptArgs){ var scriptArgs = ''; }
    if (chkObject('wantproceed')) {
        wantproceed = "Do you really want to proceed?";
    }
    var agree = confirm(wantproceed);
    if (agree)
        return scriptDoLoadPost(scriptUrl, scriptForm, scriptPos, scriptArgs);
    else
        return false;
}

function doAction(scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs, actionDiv) {
    actVal = document.getElementById(actionDiv).value;
    scriptArgs += "&sec=" + actVal;
    switch (actVal) {
        case "select":      
            break;

        case "checkstatus":
        case "edit":
        case "reports":
        case "viewreports":
        case "pagedetails":
            scriptDoLoad(scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs);
            break;

        default:
            /* check whether the system is demo or not */
            if(spdemo){
                if((actVal == 'delete') || (actVal == 'Activate') || (actVal == 'Inactivate') || (actVal == 'recheckreport') 
                    || (actVal == 'showrunproject') || (actVal == 'checkscore') || (actVal == 'deletepage') || (actVal == 'upgrade') || (actVal == 'reinstall') ){
                    alertDemoMsg();
                }
            }
            confirmLoad(scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs);
            break;
    }
}

function doLoad(argVal, scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs) {
    actVal = document.getElementById(argVal).value;
    scriptArgs += "&"+ argVal +"=" + actVal;
    scriptDoLoad(scriptUrl, scriptPos, scriptArgs);
}

function doLoadUrl(argVal, scriptUrl) {
    actVal = document.getElementById(argVal).value;
    window.location = scriptUrl += "&"+ argVal +"=" + actVal;
}

/* func to show hide menu */
function showMenu(button, scriptPos){

    for (var i=0; i<menuList.length; i++) {
        if(menuList[i] == scriptPos){
            var but = document.getElementById(button).src;
            if(but.match("more") == "more"){
                but = but.replace(/more/,"hide");
                document.getElementById(scriptPos).style.display = '';
                document.getElementById(button).src = but;

                // load default script
                if(typeof(scriptList[i]) != "undefined") {
                    scriptDoLoad(scriptList[i], 'content')
                }
            }else{
                but = but.replace(/hide/,"more");
                document.getElementById(scriptPos).style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById(button).src = but;                  
            }           
        }else{
            var butClose = document.getElementById(buttonList[i]).src;
            if(butClose.match("hide") == "hide"){
                butClose = butClose.replace(/hide/,"more");
                document.getElementById(menuList[i]).style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById(buttonList[i]).src = butClose;
            }
        }   
    }    
}

function updateArea(scriptPos, content) {
    document.getElementById(scriptPos).innerHTML += content;
}

function chkObject(theVal) {
    if (document.getElementById(theVal) != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function checkSubmitInfo(scriptUrl, scriptForm, scriptPos, catCol) {

    if(chkObject('captcha')){
        value = document.getElementById('captcha').value;
        if (value==null||value==""){
            alert('Please enter the code shown');
            return false;
        }
    }

    var obj = document.getElementsByName(catCol).item(0);
    value = obj.value;
    if (value==null||value==""||value==0){
        alert('Please select a category');
        return false;
    }

    scriptDoLoadPost(scriptUrl, scriptForm, scriptPos);
}

function loadJsCssFile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref=document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

function hideDiv(scriptPos){
    document.getElementById(scriptPos).style.display = 'none';
}

function showDiv(scriptPos){
    document.getElementById(scriptPos).style.display = '';
}

function crawlMetaData(url,scriptPos) {
    weburl = document.getElementById('weburl').value;
    if(weburl==null||weburl==""||weburl==0){
        alert('Website url is empty!');
    }else{
        url = url + "&url=" + escape(weburl);
        scriptDoLoad(url, scriptPos);
    }
}

function hideNewsBox(scriptPos, cookieVar, cookieVal) {
    hideDiv(scriptPos);
    createCookie(cookieVar, cookieVal, 1);
}

function alertDemoMsg(){
    if(spdemo){
        alert('Some features are disabled in the demo system due to security threats. Please download and install seo panel to enjoy full features.');
        exit;
    }
}

function checkDirectoryFilter(checkId, scriptUrl, scriptPos){
    var noFilter = 0;
    if(document.getElementById(checkId).checked){
        noFilter = 1;
    }

    scriptUrl = scriptUrl + "&" + checkId + "=" + noFilter;
    scriptDoLoad(scriptUrl, scriptPos);
}

function checkList(checkId) {
    checkall = document.getElementById(checkId).checked;
    for (i = 0; i < document.listform.elements.length; i++){
        if(document.listform.elements[i].type=="checkbox") {
            document.listform.elements[i].checked = checkall ? true : false;
        }
    }
}

function selectAllOptions(selectBoxId, selectAll) {

    selectBox = document.getElementById(selectBoxId);
    for (var i = 0; i < selectBox.options.length; i++) { 
        selectBox.options[i].selected = selectAll; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site comparing the commands from Prototype to the jQuery equivalents, you should find what you need for translation:

http://andykdocs.de/andykdocs/document/Migrating-from-the-Prototype-JavaScript-Framework-to-jQuery/Prototype-JS-to-jQuery-Migration-Cheat-Sheet-V1-April-2010.html